# I am chaotic and erratic

Tags: riddle

> - I am chaotic and erratic. You sometime need me, yet stay wary of me.
> - My first sibling is calm, soothing, adaptable and pure.
> - My second sibling is sturdy and reliable.
> - My third sibling is fleeting and free as can be.
> - The origin of my  cousin is forever evolving, working hard with my third sibling to make the world a better place.
> - My other cousin is very close to my second sibling. As sturdy as can be.

Who are we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> Fire, destructive yet beautiful.

Your siblings are

> Water, Calm and healing, soothing your destruction
> Earth, Mighty and placid, the foundation on which you work
> Air, Free and swift, fueling your growth

This means your cousins are

> Wood, from evolving plants, oxygenating the air to make the world better for you.
> Metal, mightier than earth, and mined therein, more resilient than most to your touch.

Comment: Good job. Although most people tend to believe in a system of 4 elements(fire, air, earth,water). There is also some who believe in a system with 5 elements(fire,water,earth,metal,wood).

Answer (score 7):

I think you might be:

> Fire, of the 4 classic elements

I am chaotic and erratic. You sometime need me, yet stay wary of me

> Fire is unpredictable, and we use it all the time but we are careful with it

My first sibling is calm, soothing, adaptable and pure.

> Water

My second sibling is sturdy and reliable.

> Earth

My third sibling is fleeting and free as can be.

> Air/ Wind

The origin of my cousin is forever evolving, working hard with my third sibling to make the world a better place.

> Could be oxygen, which is highly reactive. It circulates around the earth when blown by wind, and makes the air fresh.

My other cousin is very close to my second sibling. As sturdy as can be

> Could be carbon, which becomes diamond, the hardest material on earth.

Comment: So far so good.

Comment: The last 2 are off. The last 2 are similar to the first 4. Although using 
"cousin" instead of "sibling" does imply a certain difference.